# How to assign ajax data to @foreach( @foreach ($loans as $loan)) loop to in same view in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a view where some data is shown in a table with filtering option. When I choose an option of search from the filtering part I want only table part will be refreshed and shown the updated data. It means recent table data should clear new filtered data should show in table. I have successfully filtered data from database using Ajax. But can't show the filtered data (Ajax response) in the table.I think if ajax `data(item)` can append to `@foreach( @foreach ($loans as $loan))` problem will settle.

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')


{{--//Blade view--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

<div class="">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 borrower_id">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <h2>Pending Loans</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 "  >
                        <h6>Branch</h6>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Branch Name" aria-label="Search" id="branch_selector" name="branch_selector" value="" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" >
                        <h6>Center</h6>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Center Name" aria-label="Search" id="center_selector" name="center_selector" value="" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" >
                        <h6>Group</h6>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Group Number" aria-label="Search" id="group_selector" name="group_selector" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" >
                         <h6>Search</h6>
                        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{{-- @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <p>{{ $message }}</p>
</div>
@endif --}}

<table class="table table-bordered" id="loan_table">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Borrower No</th>
        <th>Loan Stage</th>
        <th>Loan Amount</th>

        <th>Release Date</th>


        <th width="200px">Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($loans as $loan)



    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $loan->borrower_no }}</td>
        <td>{{ $loan->loan_stage }}</td>
        <td>{{ $loan->loan_amount }}</td>

        <td>{{ $loan->release_date }}</td>

        <td width="100px">

            <form action="{{ route('approving.destroy',$loan->borrower_no) }}" method="POST">

                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{ route('approving.show',$loan->borrower_no) }}">Details of Borrower</a>
                {{--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" >Show</button>--}}
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="/approving/test/{{$loan->borrower_no}}">Approve</a>

                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Reject</button>
            </form>
        </td>

    </tr>

    @endforeach
</table>

{!! $loans->links() !!}
-------------------Ajax part---------------------

@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $(group_selector).click(function () {
            var group = $(this).val();
            console.log(group);
            var tmp = null;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '{{ ('/gseclector') }}',
                data: {'id':group},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                        
                    data.forEach(function(item){

                   $('#loan_table').append('$loans'+item);
                

                   })
                 });
                }
            });

        });
        });


</script>
```

Comment: I don't know hoe to append Ajax data(item) to @foreach,$loans variable.If any solution have please answer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is: This **is and will never be possible**.

To elaborate a bit more, you are trying to mix two very different things here. The `@foreach` loop is a blade template mechanism that is tied to php. So when a user opens your page all the **php code gets executed on the server** and is removed in the user output. So what the user gets is only html including your javascript ajax code. The **javascript code in turn is executed in the users browser**, but at that time the `@foreach` mechanism is long gone. Just open your page in a browser and use your browsers "View Sourcecode" option, to see whats left.

So you need to decide between a couple of options, here is a list for inspiration:

- Forget Ajax and do subsequent calls to a laravel get route directly and render the blade template as new page
- Use ajax and build your table directly from javascript from the ground up
- Use a js library like [datatables](https://datatables.net/) where you can throw all your data in and the user can do some sorting and filtering